# Does an Alex skill need to have an invocation name?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo

I would like to build a skill to help those with ADHD.  I'd like to teach Alexa to automatically do certain tasks, such as remind them to do certain things based on information in their calendar.

I want Alexa to help the person with ADHD manage simple daily tasks, rather than burden them with remembering to even ask for the reminder.

Example:

Rather than saying, "Alexa I'm going to school. Ask schoolPlanner what I should bring?"

They could just say "Bye Alexa, I'm going to school"

And after looking into your calendar or something, Alexa would respond, "did you remember your phone and book bag?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is in beta right now, for English skills only: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/understand-name-free-interaction-for-custom-skills.html

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible at this time:
https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/61953/invoking-custom-skill-without-ask-and-invocation-n.html